# Как правильно установить PostgreSQL на openSuse12.1?

Tags: opensuse, postgresql, django

Помогите решить проблему: пытался самостоятельно установить PostgreSQL для изучения Django, но что-то не получилось, пришлось снести PostgreSQL в Yast2 и поднять здесь вопрос о правильной и корректной установке и настройки PostgreSQL. Помогите установить и настроить под Django.

Comment: Вот про установку PostgreSQL http://ru.pokerstrategy.com/forum/thread.php?postid=1045510

Comment: извини ты читал,что там по установке? напомню - там установка под винду

Answer (score 1):

Действуем из-под рута

```
sudo -i
```

Устанавливаем PostgreSQL:

```
zypper install postgresql-server
```

Стартуем PostgreSQL:

```
rcpostgresql start
```

Заходим в управляющую консоль psql-консоль под пользователем postgres:

```
su postgres -c psql postgres
```

Выставляем новый пароль для пользователя postgres:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

Выходим из psql-консоли Ctrl+D

Прописываем в файле `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` во всех строках вместо ident - md5. Стартуем PostgreSQL:

```
rcpostgresql restart
```